# Nginx upload_module

Tags: nginx

Привет!

Сразу оговорюсь, что я не очень силен в администрирование, но установка данного модуля мне крайне необходима. Буду благодарен за помощь, а также отсутствие постов типа "читай мат часть" и т.д.

Я почитал документацию.

cd <path to nginx sources> (не совсем понял где соурс нгингса у centos) ./configure --add-module=<path to upload module sources> (ну это понятно, это куда я распаковал скачанный архив)
make
make install

Я nginx устанавливал через yum install (ОС centos), не через бинарники и ./configure выдает "no such file or directory". Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот [тут](http://centos.alt.ru/pub/repository/centos/) есть пакет Nginx и в нем уже собран данный модуль. Можно кик старыи и поставить новый, если еще не до конца свой nginx наcтроил.

Просто лучше сразу ставить собранный пакет с нужными модулями. потому что потом их отдельно искать и ставить бывает проблематично, т.к. не на всех репозиториях они есть, и приходится искать нужные репы.

Comment: Спасибо. Скорее всего так и сделаю. Только скажите, пожалуйста, как Вы узнали, что nginx-stable-1.0.14-1.el5.i386.rpm  уже с этим модулем? И я не совсем понимаю, я ведь делаю yum install nginx почему он скачивает старую версию? И как сделать, чтоб скачивал именно с указанного Вами сайта?

Comment: Ну как бы есть гугль, и много ресурсов на которых есть описание того что где содержится, все просто. Да и сам я обычно с этим репом работаю.

Comment: А ну понятно тогда, я просто подумал это можно как то посмотреть не скачав. Чтоб не скачивать попусту. Спасибо Вам.

Answer (score 2):

Команду `./configure` нужно вызывать из директории с исходниками nginx. Сами исходники можно скачать [отсюда](http://nginx.org/ru/download.html). А nginx, установленный через yum, лучше предварительно удалить.

Либо можете поискать пакет nginx'а уже собранного с upload модулем. Такие пакеты как правило называются nginx-full или nginx-extras.